# White Space coming in my website between header and main body in the Mobile View - Wordpress Website using Elementor

Tags: html, wordpress

I have tried eliminating the header after space using the wordpress. Also i have tried codes for that but still the white region exists.

problem screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you inspect the elements on PC? I want to look at the elements that is being shown in the DOM.

On further views, I can see that there is a red button saying "LOGOUT OF TEMS". Maybe you should check the CSS on that, see if it's creating any spacings.